# Have a sentence printed in Python without ' or ", using the print function

Tags: python, printing, python-2.7

Below is my code, I am working with Python2.7

```
#list of angle couples
phipsi=[[48.6,53.4],[-124.9,156.7],[-66.2,-30.8],[-58.8,-43.1], \
[-73.9,-40.6],[-53.7,-37.5],[-80.6,-16.0],[-68.5,135.0], \
[-64.9,-23.5],[-66.9,-45.5],[-69.6,-41.0],[-62.7,-37.5], \
[-68.2,-38.3],[-61.2,-49.1],[-59.7,-41.1],[-63.2,-48.5], \
[-65.5,-38.5],[-64.1,-40.7],[-63.6,-40.8],[-66.4,-44.5], \
[-56.0,-52.5],[-55.4,-44.6],[-58.6,-44.0],[-77.5,-39.1], \
[-91.7,-11.9],[48.6,53.4]]
#minimal deviation tolerated for the 1st number
a=-57-30
#maximal deviation tolerated for the 1st number
b=-57+30
#minimal deviation tolerated for the 2nd number
c=-47-30
#maximal deviation tolerated for the 2nd number
d=-47+30
i=0
#Check if the couple fit into the intervals of numbers
while i < len(phipsi):
    if phipsi[i][0]>a and phipsi[i][0]<b:
        if phipsi[i][1]>c and phipsi[i][1]<d:
            print ('the couple ', phipsi[i] ,' has his angles in helix')
    else:
        print ('the couple ', phipsi[i] ,' does not have his angles in helix')
    i=i+1
```

This is what I get

```
('the couple ', [-55.4, -44.6], ' has his angles in helix')
('the couple ', [-58.6, -44.0], ' has his angles in helix')
('the couple ', [-77.5, -39.1], ' has his angles in helix')
('the couple ', [-91.7, -11.9], ' does not have his angles in helix')
('the couple ', [48.6, 53.4], ' does not have his angles in helix')
```

How can I get

```
the couple [-77.5, -39.1] has his angles in helix
the couple [-91.7, -11.9] does not have his angles in helix
```

I checked in the help section or with other symbols but couldn't figure it out... Thank you for your help

Comment: remove the parenthesis `print 'the couple ', phipsi[i] ,' has his angles in helix'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string formatting..  Here ya go:

```
while i < len(phipsi):
    if phipsi[i][0]>a and phipsi[i][0]<b:
        if phipsi[i][1]>c and phipsi[i][1]<d:
            print ('the couple [%+.2f, %+.2f] has his angles in helix' % (phipsi[i][0], phipsi[i][1]))
    else:
        print ('the couple [%+.2f, %+.2f] does not have his angles in helix' % (phipsi[i][0], phipsi[i][1]))
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2.x `print` is not a function, but a statement, and it doesn't include parens around the list of printed objects. In Python 3.x `print` was changed to a function. You're using the Python 3.x syntax.

You have two options:

1. Use the Python 2.x syntax instead, skipping the parens: `print a, b, c`
2. Add `from __future__ import print_function` to disable the print statement and use the print function instead. This enables the use of Python 3.x syntax in recent enough Python 2.x.

At the moment you're printing a single `tuple`, and you're seeing the `repr` of that tuple, i.e. what you would get with `print((a,b,c))` with the Python 3.x print function.

Note: `print` adds spaces automatically, there is no need to add them to your strings.

Comment: That print was a statement in Python 2.x is just one of the very few mistakes.